# What does the ${-#*i} mean in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, centos6

There is a for loop in the file `/etc/profile` on CentOS 6:

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh ; do
    if [ -r "$i" ]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null 2>&1
        fi
    fi
done
```

What does the `${-#*i}` mean in the above for loop?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: When I read the title, I thought you had censored a ${-#*i}ng bad word there...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$-` means shell flags.

`${-#*i}` means shell flags minus first match of `*i`.

If these two are not equal, then the shell is considered interactive (flag `i` is present).

Comment: most confusing part  for me was the fact that loop is also using `i` as a variable - but in `${-#*i}` it is just char `i`

Answer (score 11):

See the [top answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/129234) to  [What does “${-#*i}” != “$-” mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/129231) on [Unix & Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com/) by [cuonglm](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906):

> `$-` is current option flags set by the shell itself, on invocation,
>   or using the `set` builtin command:
>
> ```
> $ echo $-
> himBH
> $ set -a
> $ echo $-
> ahimBH
> ```
>
> `"${-#*i}"` is syntax for string removal: (from [POSIX
>   documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02))
>
> > #### ${*parameter*#[*word*]}
> >
> > Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce
> >     a pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter,
> >     with the smallest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern
> >     deleted.
> >
> > If present, word shall not begin with an unquoted '`#`'.
> >
> > #### ${*parameter*##[*word*]}
> >
> > Remove Largest Prefix Pattern. The word shall be expanded to produce a
> >     pattern. The parameter expansion shall then result in parameter, with
> >     the largest portion of the prefix matched by the pattern deleted.
>
> So `${-#*i}` remove the shortest string till the first `i` character:
>
> ```
> enter code here
> $ echo "${-#*i}"
> mBH
> ```
>
> In your case, `if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]` checking if your shell is
>   interactive or not.

Comment: I've edited your answer to properly quote and attribute the original author. Have a look at [Referencing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) in the help centre; the recommendation is to "quote only the relevant portion", not the full answer.

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr:**

**Conditional `[ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]` evaluates to logical *true* if the current shell is *interactive***, in which case the exit code is set to `0`, signaling *true*, which causes the enclosing `if` statement's `then` branch to be executed.

The conditional and the code in the question as a whole intentionally use only [**POSIX-compliant shell-language syntax and commands**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) so as to be **portable** (work with all POSIX-*compatible* shells that may act as `/bin/sh`).

<sup>Note that if `bash` could be assumed as the shell, for instance, the same conditional could be more readably expressed as

`[[ $- == *i* ]]`</sup>

---

#### Explanation

- `${-#*i}` is a [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) that removes the shortest prefix (`#`) that matches [pattern](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) `*i` from the value of named parameter `$-` (a named parameter is more commonly called a *variable*).
- `$-` is a [special parameter](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02), which (link and emphasis added):

  > expands to the **current [option](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html#tag_20_117_04) flags** (the **single-letter option names concatenated into a string**) as specified on invocation, by the set special built-in command, or implicitly by the shell.
- **An *interactive* shell *implicitly* adds option flag `i` to the value of `$-`**; in other words: the presence of letter `i` in the value of `$-` implies that the shell at hand is *interactive*, and, conversely, the *absence* of `i` implies that the shell is *noninteractive*.
- Thus, in parameter expansion `${-#*i}`, pattern `*i` will only match inside the value of `$-` if an `i` is present, and, if so, by virtue of *removing* what `*i` matched, return a *substring* (suffix, in this case) of `$-`.
  In other words: only in an *interactive* shell does `${-#*i}` *not* equal `$-`, because in a *noninteractive* shell - due to the absence of `i` - the parameter expansion has *no* effect, and the two operands are equal.

---

#### **What the code in the question does *as a whole***:

In short: The code uses shell scripts it finds in `/etc/profile.d` to initialize the current shell; more specifically:

- Scripts (files named `*.sh`) located in directory `/etc/profile.d` that are readable by the current user (`-r`) are passed to the [`.` (dot) utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) one by one, in alphabetical order. The dot utility executes the commands from each file in the *current*  shell, typically to define aliases, functions, and environment variables. This is commonly known as *sourcing* a file.
- *Output* produced by each sourced script is handled differently depending on whether the current shell is interactive or not:

  - *interactive* shell: output is *passed through* (will be visible in the interactive shell).
  - *noninteractive* shell: output is *suppressed* (`>/dev/null 2>&1` is the POSIX-compliant way to silence both stdout and stderr).